# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderSco

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, provider

i am trying to load api data in init state with provider ,but this error is throwing,i wrapped parent widget with multiprovider and added changenotifier provider also, seems like some error with context of provider but i coudnt find the issue

```
  bool isPostdataloading = false;
  bool iscommentsLoading = false;

  List<CommentsModelData> commentsCollections = [];
  List<SingleUserPostModelData> userPostCollections = [];

  

  @override
  void initState() {
   

    super.initState();
  
   getpostdata();
    getComments();
  }

  getpostdata() async {
    setState(() {
      isPostdataloading = true;
    });
    userPostCollections =
        await SingleUserPostService().getSingleuserPost(postid: widget.postid);

    print(userPostCollections[0].commentCount);

    setState(() {
      isPostdataloading = false;
    });
  }

  getComments() async {
    setState(() {
      iscommentsLoading = true;
    });

    commentsCollections =
        Provider.of<CommentPageProvider>(context).loadComments(widget.postid);
    // commentsCollections =
    //     await CommentService().getCommentsdata(post_id: widget.postid);

    //  print(commentsCollections[0].status);

    setState(() {
      iscommentsLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController commentTextEditingController =
        TextEditingController();

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CommentPageProvider>(
      create: (context) => CommentPageProvider(),
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: postcomment(widget.postid),
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happened because you used `context` that related to the parents of `ChangeNotifierProvider`, try put your functions inside `addPostFrameCallback`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     getpostdata();
     getComments();  
  });
  
}
```

Comment: @Diljith was it what you looking for?